# Why a Typescript Record with a union of a primitive and a specific string makes the string mandatory?

Tags: typescript, types, optional-chaining

I have this type:

```
type ErrorMessages = Record<number | 'default', string>;
```

Then, when I define a variable as `const text: ErrorMessages = {403: 'forbidden'}`, Typescript says that `default` is missing in the type:

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAshAzughgcw1AXigCUIBjZAEwB4A7AVwFsAjCOKAHygHJKIAzLPQA2wbgBoo6YHACWtHAD4A3ACgKtaVGAQAHsABcsBMjSZc+IgG8ALAAYAzEe79kzWZT61uAXyA)

Why a Typescript Record with a union of a primitive and a specific string makes the string mandatory?

Comment: Really interesting, I never considered this behavior before. Nice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Record` distributes the union you give for the key argument, creating an object type requiring *all* of those keys. In your IDE or the TypeScript playground, if you hover over `ErrorMessages`, you'll see the expanded definition of it, which makes the problem clear:

```typescript
type ErrorMessages = {
    [x: number]: string;
    default: string;
}
```

Similarly, `Reocrd<"a" | "b", string>` requires **both** `a` and `b` properties.

Instead, you can define `ErrorMessages` as an object type directly, explicitly while making `default` optional via a postfix `?`, like this:

```
type ErrorMessages = {
    [key: number]: string;
    default?: string;
};
```

That allows both of your assignments:

```
const text1: ErrorMessages = { 403: "forbidden" };
const text2: ErrorMessages = { default: "something else" };
```

That will also allow multiple messages, which I **think** is correct given the type name `ErrorMessages` (plural):

```
const text3: ErrorMessages = {
    default: "something else",
    403: "forbidden",
};
```

...while disallowing other string keys:

```
// Error as desired
const text4: ErrorMessages = { foo: "bar" };
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^ Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ErrorMessages'.
//                                        Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type 'ErrorMessages'. (2322)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAshAzughgcw1AXigG8AoKCqAbQGsIQAuKAOwFcBbAIwjgF0n0wOAEtmOANzlKAEwgAzLKwA2wAPwChoiaQC+k0gGNEzQVGAQAHsACMTeElQZsedIRJQALAAYAzEwBEcsicwtKyzP5QeobGpuZWAEx2CMhomLj4RMRQsgrKwAHoiOwQwAAWWlAQSugQkdExJsBmlsB+sCmO6S5uZJQ58ooqhcWlFWJVNXUANFIU3u2BwaHh-rMNAPQbHQ5QWK6y6MJwENKNca0eyQ5pzpnuQYgBnFhw9eJAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type, like so:

```
type ErrorMessages = Partial<Record<number | 'default', string>>
```